# How to get previous months data using KDB query?

Tags: sql

How can I retrieve data from the previous month in such a way that, if the query were to be automated, the date value in the query would change accordingly, every month?

So for example:
When query is run on **2012.01.01** --> select * from Table where date >= **2011.12.01**
When query is run on **2012.02.01** --> select * from Table where date >= **2012.01.01**
When query is run on **2012.03.01** --> select * from Table where date >= **2012.02.01**

and so on..

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Oracle Database;

```
select * from Table where date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-1)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned - its a Sybase Db.

Comment: thanks very much for that! Do you know how I can connect to a kdb database via a unix script? ie, connection syntax

Comment: You should accept this solution and create new entry for your next question